# pass a jquery object from one plugin to another

Tags: jquery, object, plugins

I am trying to create an html element with one jquery plugin then pass the jquery object created to another plugin for more modifications.
for example : 1 plugin would create the object the second one would add css ( i know this isnt the best way to do things) but a 3rd plugin calls the first one then the second one.
I hope my description was clear :)
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use normal jQuery [chai](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx#tip10)[ning](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2007/10/26/jQuery-Understanding-the-chain) ?

```
jQuery(myObject).firstThing().secondThing().thirdThing();
```

Comment: I was thinking something more like this :

$.fn.plugin1 = function(options) { 
//function
return jqueryobject

}
$.fn.plugin2 = function(options) { }
$.fn.plugin3 = function(options) {
object = $('selector').plugin1()
$(object).plugin2()
 }

this however isnt working

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on the plugin code. Maybe you could give us an example.

Given your above description, the following may suffice:

```
$.thirdPluginFunc($.secondPluginFunc($.firstPluginFunc()));

//$.firstPluginFunc - Create the object
//$.secondPluginFunc - Apply the CSS
```